# How to iterate over material index using Python

Tags: python, scripting, materials

[image]

I want to iterate over the material index of material slot and change the value of each material index. How can this be done in Python?

I've tried using the Python shown below, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.object
material = object.active_material
for num in range(0, 5):
    object.active_material_index = num
    if material.use_shadeless:
       material.use_shadeless = False 
    else:
       material.use_shadeless = True
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way to loop over the object's materials is through its [`material_slots`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_0/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.material_slots) attribute. Here's an equivalent code for toggling all object materials shadeless property:

```
import bpy

for m in bpy.context.object.material_slots:
    m.material.use_shadeless = not m.material.use_shadeless
```

The only issue I see in your own code is that you're assigning the material to a variable *before* changing active material index, which renders the latter operation moot. Changing the index before assigning the resulting material to a variable, will yield the result you want.

Comment: this work best, using material_slots seems solve the issue

Comment: doesn't look like it works for you. maybe further testing is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The error with the script is its not re-assigning `material`.

Corrected script:

```
import bpy

object = bpy.context.object
for num in range(0, 5):
    object.active_material_index = num
    material = object.active_material  # <-- changed line
    if material.use_shadeless:
       material.use_shadeless = False 
    else:
       material.use_shadeless = True
```

@Adhi's method is nicer, just showing what the mistake was.

Comment: aahh...so I just missed one line, thanks for pointing it out Campbell.